# Multiple editable SVGs on a page

Tags: css, performance, svg, css-transitions

I'm looking for a sanity check on an idea I'm considering implementing. I'm working on a client list page and I want some transition effects on the logos. For now, it's going to be a colour transition from white to gray but who knows what else down the line. I can't use something like CSS `grayscale()` filter because in my tests white isn't getting changed to gray. (And that makes sense, right???).

So I was thinking that I could use SVGs instead (either outputting them inline or more than likely as an SVG image). In terms of practical management it isn't going to be an issue to either create the SVGs or upload the logos to the site so I'm wondering about things like performance or just generally thoughts on whether having 20+ individual SVGs (which can be pretty weighty in terms of markup) is madness. I've not used SVGs a whole lot so excuse me if the answer is obvious.

On the other hand, I'm thinking that if I stick to pngs I'd have to create functionality to add 40 images (20 white and 20 gray versions) and this seems like a bad idea from a performance perspective and also like a massive pain in the you know what.

Comment: Try it and see, just find an image, load in 20 of them (doesn't matter if they are the same, just try and get ones with similar complexity) and animate one or whatever. Test on mobile and see how it looks first for a lowest common denominator.

Comment: @Ian will do. I asked Sara Soueidan (pretty much THE expert on SVG) and she was of the opinion that I'd be mad not to. (I'm putting words in her mouth but that was the gist.